# Failed to set remote candidates :-( (added 1, expected 2)

Tags: websocket, webrtc, janus, janus-gateway, videocall

when try to check video call sessions created successfully but there no video stream happens in janus gateway webrtc

```
    Creating new session: 7295874067549813; 0x7fec98004230
Creating new handle in session 7295874067549813: 2264190151434116; 0x7fec98004230 0x7fec98005430
Creating new session: 3622043621310499; 0x5557f104b700
Creating new handle in session 3622043621310499: 3486814800053046; 0x5557f104b700 0x7fec98008f60
[ERR] [transports/janus_http.c:janus_http_handler:1239] Invalid url /ws/v1/cluster/apps/new-application
[3486814800053046] Creating ICE agent (ICE Full mode, controlled)
[2264190151434116] Creating ICE agent (ICE Full mode, controlling)
[ERR] [ice.c:janus_ice_setup_remote_candidates:3180] [2264190151434116] Failed to set remote candidates :-( (added 1, expected 2)
[WARN] [2264190151434116]     Missing valid SRTP session (packet arrived too early?), skipping...
[WARN] [2264190151434116]     Missing valid SRTP session (packet arrived too early?), skipping...
[WARN] [2264190151434116]     Missing valid SRTP session (packet arrived too early?), skipping...
[WARN] [3486814800053046]     Missing valid SRTP session (packet arrived too early?), skipping...
[WARN] [2264190151434116]     Missing valid SRTP session (packet arrived too early?), skipping...
[WARN] [3486814800053046]     Missing valid SRTP session (packet arrived too early?), skipping...
[2264190151434116] The DTLS handshake has been completed
[janus.plugin.videocall-0x7fec98004430] WebRTC media is now available
[WARN] [2264190151434116] Not video and not audio? dropping (SSRC 3036569962)...
[WARN] [2264190151434116] Not video and not audio? dropping (SSRC 3126498254)...
[WARN] [2264190151434116] Not video and not audio? dropping (SSRC 4083758620)...
```

any idea how to fix this....

Comment: yes it was the issue with turn server, check your turn server configurations and add your turn IPin nat_1_1 config

Comment: yes, conturn only used. it working fine now.....

you can try this and check also   https://numb.viagenie.ca/